# Conduction electron density and atoms per volume, help with equations

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics

I need help understanding these two equations. 
I cannot figure out their relationship and why they are correct.

Starting from the first equation, can I derive the second?
Can I derive any them from the "normal" mass density $\rho=m/V$? And also, why is $\rho_m$ missing in the second equation?

The conduction electron density is $n=Z_v\rho_m/M$, where $M$ is the atomic mass in kilgrams per atom and $\rho_m$ is the density of the solid in $\text{kg m}^{-3}$. Every atoms contributes $Z_v$ conduction electrons.

Atoms per cubic meter = $\rho_m/M$

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't understand it. Is it about setting $m=MN$ and $n=N/V$?

Comment: @ Sanya Yes, how you can relate $n=N/V$ and $m=MN$ to the equations above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the number of conduction electrons n per $m^3$, you first need to know the number of atoms per $m^3$. The number of atoms per $m^3$ you get by dividing the mass per $m^3$, which is $\rho_m$, by the atomic mass M. The number of atoms per $m^3$ is thus  $ρ_m/M$. This number you have to multiply by the number of conduction electrons per atom $Z_v$ to obtain the number of conduction electrons per $m^3$, which gives the conduction electron density $n=Z_v\rho_m/M$.